# Java Arrays - unsure about methods

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have been set a Java assignment which is basically a model of a restaurant. I have mostly completed it apart from the most difficult part. It is basically dealing with Arrays and objects; there are several parts of which I'm unsure about. I have already completed classes implementing an ArrayList and another using a Map/HashMap.

This is what I have so far:

```
package restaurant;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;


public class ArrayOrder implements Order {

    Product order[];

    public ArrayOrder() {
        this.order = new Product[1000];
    }

    public Iterator<Product> iterator() {

    }


    public void addItem(Product product, int quantity) {    
        /*for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            this.order[i] = product; // WRONG CODE
        }*/
    }


    public void removeItem(Product product) {

    }


    public int numberOfItems() {
        int length = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.order.length; i++){
            if(this.order[i] != null) {
                length++;
            }
        }
        return length;
    }


    public int totalCost() {
        int resultcost = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.order.length; i++) {
            if(this.order[i] != null) {
                    resultcost += this.order[i].getCost();
            }
        }
        return resultcost;
    }

    public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(this.order);
    }

    public int hashCode() {

    }

    public boolean equals() {

    }
}
```

I have read that you cannot make an array of an undefined length but I am not sure how one would deal with this; if I initialise the array to be a certian number, errors are likely to occur. Say if I initialise the array to [10] and the user adds 20 products, it is going to error.

The second problem is the addItem function; I know the problem with the logic that I have written here is that the index of the array that product is being written to is ONLY going to ever be as big as quantity so the array index of quantity is where the product is being written to; not searching through 'this.order' and finding a NULL array value and writing the product by the amount of times specified by the quantity paramiter. I am not sure where to go with this really.

The next problem is the removeItem function which I imagine uses a similar sort of logic to the addItem. I have not written anything here as my attempts have been wrong and I couldn't get the addItem function to work for a start so I left this.

The last problem is the toString method. The toString method gets the whole array defined (SAY this.order = new Product[10]) which I don't really want it to do.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
//int id, String name, String description, int cost, int serves

Starter s = new Starter(25, "Salad", "A traditional English salad", 750, 1);
Order o3 = new ArrayOrder();
o3.addItem(s, 2);
```

THE `toString` METHOD PRODUCES:

```
[Salad - A traditional English salad (serves 1) $7.50, Salad - A traditional English salad (serves 1) $7.50, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

I want it to stop before null, null, null etc.. but it is taking in the whole Array and 8 of them are null values; I'm unsure about how to fix this. Is there anyway around the Array and defining its length; in my example above I have only added 2 items but I declared an Array of length [10]; how would I know what length to define the Array? If the user added 20 starters in my example above, the program would crash...

The numberOfItems & totalCost functions work when I have tested them with a main method.

Any guidance to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

EDIT:
I think I have been a little unclear; the requirements are that I am to create several classes based on a UML diagram. At this I have to create 3 classes that all implement an Order interface. The three classes are (ListOrder, ArrayOrder, MapOrder). I have done the MapOrder and the ListOrder but I am stuck on the ArrayOrder.

Here is my ArrayList class:

```
package restaurant;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class ListOrder implements Order{

    private List<Product> order;

    public ListOrder() {
        this.order = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    public Iterator<Product> iterator() {
        return order.iterator();
    }


    public void addItem(Product product, int quantity) {
        for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            this.order.add(product);
        }
    }


    public void removeItem(Product product) {
        this.order.remove(product);
    }


    public int numberOfItems() {
        return this.order.size();
    }


    public int totalCost() {
        int resultcost = 0;
        for(Product p : order)
        {
            resultcost += p.getCost();
        }
        return resultcost;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.order.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get why you can't use an `ArrayList` internally. Is it explicitly forbidden? You are trying to model a dynamic array with a static array and that's exactly what `ArrayList` does.

Comment: An [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a "dynamic array" that provides you with a automatic re-sizable "array", which also includes add/insert and remove methods built in.

Comment: I don't see you using an ArrayList at all.  Using an ArrayList is a way to create a collection when you don't know its size.

Comment: For the `toString()` issue, you need to keep track of the number of items independently from your array size.  An int field counter would do the trick nicely.  And take a closer look at your `numberOfItems()` implementation too...

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in Java are fixed in size: upon instantiation, a size must be provided. The array will never change in size after instantiation.

What you need is a facility to define a dynamic-sized array. For that, many facilities exist within the standard JDK. Look at the `List` interface, and its various implementations (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and so forth).

Comment: "immutable" means something pretty specific - might want to use a different word there. (e.g unchangeable)

Answer (score 0):

Some points:

- you are importing `ArrayList`, `Arrays`, `Iterator` but never use them, what is the purpose? You are just using a static array that have the problems you mentioned.
- you should consider using an `ArrayList` to internally store your elements, why would you bother managing a static array that must grow if needed when there is a class that wraps this functionality right for you? (actually a `LinkedList` is better in your situation, take a look at next point)
- by looking at what you should provide to the outside I see than you don't need random access, this means that, if you really want to roll your own collection, you should model it as a ***linked list*** because you won't have the problems you mentioned (like having to increase size of the array or managing null values).

Comment: Hi, I have been messing with the code and I forgot to delete some of the things that I imported. I plan to write the Iterator function after I have got the add & remove functions working. Thanks for the help,

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have implemented the same functionality using `ArrayList` and `Map`, and now you are required to implement it using arrays.

The easiest thing to do is keep an extra field with the number of valid elements. Do not rely on finding a `null` element as this is inefficient and prone to error (particularly if the requirements suddenly change and you are required to allow for `null` elements).

You also need a `int quantities[]` field to maintain quantities. These two arrays should always be the same size.

Then, when you have to add a new element, you can compare the number of valid elements with `order.length` (the "capacity" of the current allocation). If adding the new element would exceed the capacity, then you simply need to reallocate `order`:

```
public void addItem(Product product, int quantity) {    
    if (currentSize >= order.length) {
        Product[] temp = new Product[order.length + GROWTH_FACTOR];
        System.arraycopy(order, 0, temp, 0, currentSize);
        order = temp;
        int[] q2 = new int[order.length + GROWTH_FACTOR];
        System.arraycopy(quantities, 0, q2, 0, currentSize);
        quantities = q2;
    }
    quantities[currentSize] = quantity;
    order[currentSize++] = product;
}
```

Here `GROWTH_FACTOR` is a constant for how much to expand the array when you run out of room.

Alternatively, you can introduce a private static class that keeps a product/quantity pair:

```
private static class OrderItem {
    final Product product;
    final int quantity;
    OrderItem(Product product, int quantity) {
        this.product = product;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}

private OrderItem[] orders;
private int currentSize;

public void addItem(Product product, int quantity) {
    if (currentSize >= orders.length) {
        // reallocate orders array
    }
    orders[currentSize++] = new OrderItem(product, quantity);
}
```

Comment: I'm  a little unsure about the first bit of code; what is the currentSize variable and how would one implement/determine the GROWTH_FACTOR? Thanks for the help,

Comment: @user1874133 - `currentSize` should be a field of your `ArrayOrder` class. It should start out at `0` and should be incremented by one every time you add an order and decremented every time you remove an order. It should always be equal to the number of valid orders (slots of the `orders` array that contain valid data). `GROWTH_FACTOR` is totally arbitrary--it can be any positive integer. The smaller it is, the more frequently you'll have to reallocate the array(s) as you add orders; the larger it is, the more space is potentially wasted. A value of `10` might work nicely.

Comment: @user535871 - at the top of my class I have put int currentSize = 0;   -  in my addItem method, I have just put currentSize++ (above the if statement). It is in this method that I have defined GROWTH_FACTOR as 10. Am I heading in the right direction with this?....... Also I am getting a few errors with the quantities variable... Thanks for the help,

Comment: @user1874133 - Generally the right direction, with a few recommendations. Don't increment `currentSize` until _after_ you test whether you need to expand the array(s). Regarding `GROWTH_FACTOR`--the usual style would be to define this as `private static final int GROWTH_FACTOR = 10;` at the class level, rather than buried inside a method. The `quantities` variable should be another array defined as a member field of `ArrayOrder`. (I introduced this because my understanding is that you need to keep Product/quantity pairs.)